# HP ML310e Gen8 v2 is really noisy

Tags: hardware, hp, hp-proliant, fan

I have a ML310e Gen8 v2 and a problem on initial setup the server.
The problem is with the Fan noise and speed.
The server is fully updated with the latest firmware available from HP and the setting in BIOS for Thermal Control is set to Optimal.
But these fans doesn't calm down at all.

Any suggestions will be very appreciated.

Comment: Yeah, things that spin at 10,000 RPM are loud.  What of it?

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you running?

Regardless of the OS, you should install the [HP drivers and management agents appropriate for the OS](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/swdHome/?cc=us&cc=us&lang=en&lang=en&sp4ts.oid=5379532&ac.admitted=1415200109599.876444892.199480143). If using an unsupported OS, you may not be able to do this (but you should be using a supported OS)

Fan speed and thermal monitoring is controlled by the ILO. Ensure that the ILO itself is up-to-date (version 2.02, as of this writing).

You should have [several BIOS options for fan speed](https://serverfault.com/questions/330858/hp-proliant-dl180-g6-fan-noise). Optimal, Maximum Cooling and for some tower servers, a Reduced Acoustics mode. Select the appropriate option.

Evaluate the PCIe expansion cards installed. If you have certain cards in place, the system [may ramp fan speed up](https://serverfault.com/questions/312021/controlling-hp-proliant-dl380-g6-g7-fan-speed) regardless of the BIOS setting.

What disks are you using? if not using HP drives, there's a chance that [their temperature is reported incorrectly](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-ML-DL-SL/Proliant-ML310e-Gen8-making-a-LOT-of-noise/td-p/6192091#.VFo71r7DvSw). This can also be a source of issues.

Comment: The server is installed with Windows Server 2012 R2 and it has 2 drives HP 1 TB each and they're non hot plug sata drives.

Comment: @networkpro Are the [HP Management Agents for Windows 2012 installed](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=5379532&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3DswEnvOID%253D4168%257CswLang%253D%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken#Software%20-%20System%20Management)?

Comment: Yes all the managements are installed also i forget to mention that stock Quadro Gpu is present and I'll try the stated suggestions.

Comment: @networkpro You have an Nvidia Quadro graphics card installed in the server's PCIe slot? If so, that's probably the cause of the fan issue.

Comment: Actually I have mistaken there is no a Pci graphics card, Today a guy from HP came and upgrade the iLO from version 2.2 to 2.5 because I  don't have access to their resources for such newer version and he got the server to their local office for warranty servicing due to a firmware brick which he did I think :D on upgrade :D

Comment: So you'll get a new motherboard. Hopefully that fixes your problem.